# How do I figure out the time complexities/recurrence relation of the following codes?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, permutation, recurrence

```
def permute2(string, current=''):
    """ Returns a list of all possible permutations of string """
    if len(string) == 1:
        return [current + string]
    ans = []
    for i in string:
        ans += permute2(string.replace(i, ''), current + i)
    return ans


def permutation(a):
    if len(a) < 1:
        return [""]
    t = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in permutation(a[:i] + a[i+1:]):
            t.append(a[i] + j)
    return t
```

permute2() should have a recurrence relation of T(n) = n*T(n-1) + c, I think.

However, I am very confused for permutation(). I thought it would be T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n^2, but I don't think that's quite right since that's what the recurrence relation would be if the second for loop didn't exist and only does a recursive call.
Like:

```
for i in range (len(a)):
    permutation(a[:i] + a[i+1:]
```

Comment: You have included the tag for Big O and seem to be trying to express Big O time complexity using T which is contrary to normal practice of using O(n) format.  What is your question?  Also, when computing Big O complexity it is normal practice to not worry about constants which are added to or multiplied with Big O

Comment: I am trying to create a code that has better time complexity than permutation(). However, I have trouble finding out what is the time complexity of permutation(). In my school, we were taught to express the problem using recurrence relation in order to accurately find Big O.

Comment: What does permute2 have do do with anything?

Comment: Based on my analysis both permute2 and permutation have complexity of O(2^n) because for each char in input, you run through the entire list.  This implies 2 to the nth power.